# For-loop not printing all the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var dd = new Date();
var nn = dd.getDay();

console.log(nn);

var dates = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
var ordered = [];
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
         console.log(nn+i)
         ordered.push(dates[nn+i])
}

console.log(ordered);
```

Hi hi, I am having problems with this for. Now I can get the current day, search within the array and print from that day. BUT, the problem is that the previous days are not printed.

The code above will print an array of 7 elements:

```
["Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

nn+1 does an iteration from 3 to 9, being 7, 8 and 9 blank. If you are wondering why I put "Domingo" (Sunday) as the first element of the array is because how [getDay()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) works.

Without modifying the length of the array how can I add the other days that are not being printed? Answer may be obvious but I'm stuck...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of the *module operator* `%`? Do some research about it, and experiment with it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think you mean "modulo" (or [more accurately](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-mod-operator) I'm told, "remainder").

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah yes. My spelling isn't what it's used to be. Especially since "module" is a valid word and the spell-checker don't catch it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code above will print an array of 7 elements

That will depend on what day it is, because you have:

```
var nn = dd.getDay();
```

and then in your loop:

```
ordered.push(dates[nn+i])
```

Then `nn+` part of that doesn't belong there.

If your goal is to make day `nn` the first day in the array, followed by the others in sequence, use the `remainder` operator so that the result of `nn+i` is wrapped around to the beginning of the array:

```
ordered.push(dates[(nn+i) % dates.length])
```

At first, `nn+i` is in range, so for instance if `nn` is 3, you have `(3+0) % 7` which is `3 % 7` which is 3. But later as `i` increases, you reach the point where `nn+i` is beyond the end of the array; the `%` operator wraps it around for you. For instance, when you get to the fifth loop iteration, you have `(3+4) % 7` which is `7 % 7` which is `0`.

Live Example:

```js
var dd = new Date();
var nn = dd.getDay();

console.log(nn);

var dates = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
var ordered = [];
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    console.log(nn+i);
    ordered.push(dates[(nn+i) % dates.length]);
}

console.log(ordered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I did it purposely because I want to print nn day the first one in the array.

Comment: @Calicorio: The `nn` day of the first *what*?

Comment: The first position in the new array generated.

Comment: @Calicorio: I've updated the answer with a guess at what you mean by "the first one."

Comment: Oh! That's it! You guys were right, I didn't think about modulus length for the array. I'll mark your answer as right when the page allows me! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fix this with the modulo operator to make the index wrap around. Because you add the day to the current index you are moving past the limits of the array and undefined is added to the array.

```
var dd = new Date();
var nn = dd.getDay();

console.log(nn);

var dates = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
var ordered = [];
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
         console.log((nn+i) % dates.length)
         ordered.push(dates[(nn+i) % dates.length])
}

console.log(ordered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is what you want to do

```
var dd = new Date();
var nn = dd.getDay();

console.log(nn);

var dates = [
  'Domingo',
  'Lunes',
  'Martes',
  'Miércoles',
  'Jueves',
  'Viernes',
  'Sábado',
];
var ordered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  console.log((nn + i) % 7);
  ordered.push(dates[(nn + i) % 7]);
}

console.log(ordered);
```

Its uses modulo 7 (7 days per week) so the index does not go over the length of the array. You can read more about this operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) under `Remainder`

Instead of hard coding the value 7 you can also use `% dates.length`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting out of the length of `dates[]`. When you reach "Sabado", in the next iteration, you have to start pointing at `dates[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of doing this:
(Check out https://jsfiddle.net/ujvwckcu/)

```
var dd = new Date();
var nn = dd.getDay();
var days = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];

// Array of all days from the current one till the end of the week
var ordered = days.slice(nn, 7);

// Array of all days before current one
var rest = days.slice(0, nn);

// Merge all days before to the days after array (will append at the end)
rest.forEach(function (value) {
    ordered.push(value);
})

console.log('ordered', ordered);
```

Comment: Yes, there is. This isn't it.

Answer (score -1):

or to keep it simple

```
var dd = new Date();
var nn = dd.getDay();

console.log(nn);

var dates = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
var ordered = [];
for(var i = nn; i < dates.length; i++) {
         console.log(i)
         ordered.push(dates[i])
}
for(var i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
         console.log(i)
         ordered.push(dates[i])
}
console.log(ordered);
```

Comment: This is not simpler than `%`, it's more complicated.

Comment: for person who dont know modulus it is simpler.

Comment: By that logic, for someone who doesn't know the `for` loop, it would be "simpler" to do something even more complicated. Doesn't justify complicating it.

Comment: It is not for you to judge.